# Assuring whether URL provides JSON or not

Tags: android, json

I want to check whether the given url provides contents in JSON or not. How can I accomplish this? I'm using following method to read the JSON from URL. I didn't get any answers for this topic. I need help to accomplish this.

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            resultOk=true;
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                jsonString = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error",
                        "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
        } else {
            resultOk=false;
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
            jsonObjects = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    // return JSON String
    return jsonObjects;
}
```

Comment: I think topic should be "Assuring whether URL provides JSON or not". Sorry for that.

Comment: Parse the string using standard JSON parser. If you can't parse its not JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your response string. If it starts with " { " or " [ " character then it means that response is in json format.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
        jsonObjects = new JSONObject(jsonString);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}
```

this itself should be enough to test if you actually got JSON.

If you didn't the exception should be raised. Just checking if the String you received starts with '{' is not really any indication: 
{this is not valid JSON..}

Comment: I did the same but the application gets crashed while exception is encountered, if i provide the wrong url like this:
           Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler           inside     thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: could you post the stacktrace?

Comment: at json.JSONObjectParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONObjectParser.java:77) and line 77 is : jsonObjects=new JSONObject(jsonString);

Comment: What type of exception is it? It can't be a JSONException since your catching that.

Comment: I wonder I'm also unaware of this. Its works fine if I provide the valid URL but when I provide the invalid URL then application goes crash. That's why, I first want to check whether the URL provides the valid JSON or not.

Comment: Umn you don't know what Exception causes your App to crash? This is becoming more confusing by the minute, shouldn't your stack trace tell you exactly that?

Comment: Thankyou cania.. finally i got the right things to do. I've posted updated one.

Answer (score 1):

[Closed] I got the right solution by changing and checking the "resultOk" flag. Here it goes:

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            resultOk = true;
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                jsonString = sb.toString();
                jsonObjects = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error",
                        "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                resultOk = false;
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
        } else {
            resultOk = false;
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonObjects;
}
```

And from calling part:

```
if (JSONObjectParser.resultOk){
    //Show Success dialog with some good message
    //And rest of the code....  
} else{
    //Show Error dialog with some error message
    //And rest of the code....
}
```

Finally this one works fine for me. Thankyou all...

Answer (score 0):

This is the valid json format

```
{
"ECom": "",
"EDept": "01",
"EFlr": "GF",
"EComId": "",
"EDeptId": "01",
"EFlrId": "GF",
"EName": "EMPLOYEE 1",
"ECode": "00000001",
"VId": "201200000002",
"VName": "",
"VComp": "",
"VAddr": "",
"VMob": "",
"VEmail": "",
"VContact": "",
"VCat": "3",
"VPurpose": "1",
"VLaptop": "LAPTOP",
"VBel": "",
"VGender": "M",
"VRmk1": "",
"VRmk2": "",
"NOV": ""
}
```

Comment: you can build your if conditions based in this